# Java Class Circular Reference

Tags: java, class, reference

I've been some java code in an attempt to understand what is happening when the game is launched.  In my review, I have encountered what appears to be a circular reference that I just don't understand.  I've left out a lot of the extraneous code to highlight the area that I'm finding confusing.  Let me know if there is something confusing and I'll try to supply as much information as possible.

The game data class (simplified here) holds information about the different elements of the game.  This can include player data (detailed here), unit information, map board information, etc.  All of the objects used in the game contain a reference to the GameData class.

When the program is launched the load method of the the LoadGameData class is executed.  It's purpose is to query a SQLite database and load information into memory.  In the example, below, the method gets a reference to the playerList contained in the GameData object.  It then queries the database and create a player object for each record returned.  As each player object is created it is also given a reference to the GameData object and is then added to the PlayerList which itself is a member of the GameData object.

Doesn't this represent a circular reference?

Also, it seems to me then, using this logic each object in the game will have a reference to all of the other objects in the game.  Is that correct?  Of course I'm assuming that this merely a pointer reference to the GameData object and not a full on copy of the GameData object.

```
class GameComponenent {
    private GameData m_data;
    public GameComponent(final GameData data) {
        m_GameData = data
    }
}

class Player extends GameComponent {
    public Player(String key, GameData data) {
        super(data);
    }
}

class GameData() {
    private PlayerList playerList = new PlayerList(this);
    private TerritoryList territories = new TerritoryList(this);
    private resourceList resources = new ResourceList(this);

    [The list goes on]

    public PlayerList getPlayerList() {
        return playerList;
    }
}

public class PlayerList extends GameDataComponent 
    public PlayerList(final GameData data) {
        super(data);
    }

    protected void addPlayer(final Player player) {
        m_players.put(player.getName(), player);
    }
}

class loadGameData() {
    GameData data;

    public void load() {
        data = new GameData();
        loadPlayerData(getPlayerDataFromDatabase());
    }

    public void loadPlayerData(Map<String, Map<String, String>> input) {
        PlayerList pl = data.getPlayerList();
        foreach (Player p : PlayerXMLNodes) {
            Player p = new Player(key, data);
            pl.addPlayer(Player);        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a circular reference. If that is a problem, you can pass the ``GameData`` to every method that needs access to it instead of passing it to constructors and kepping it in fields. All variables except for primitive type ones (``int``,``byte`` etc.) are references.

Comment: I think that I'm tracking with you.  So, if I were to run a multi-threaded application, I could use such a method to allow the threads to update a common object .... provided that there was an appropriate locking mechanism in place.  Is that right?

Comment: You need locking or a non-locking thread-safe way to access/mutate shared data. The ``java.util.concurrent`` package has many building blocks for that. When handling more than one unit of mutable state, you'll also usually want to make your mutations atomic (to avoid i.e. dirty writes) and make sure you're locking things in a specific order (or else you'll run into deadlocks).